# Conditional Expectation and Conditional Varience

Tags: conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

Suppose that X|Y = p has a Binomial(n,p) distribution for 0 < p <1 and Y has a U(0,1) distribution. Find E(X) and Var(X).

Comment: What mean $X|Y=p$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, but i did not understand the question at all, because there is a binomial and uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf EX=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))=\mathsf EnY=n\mathsf EY=\frac12n$.

You can find $\mathsf{Var}X$ on base of $\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathsf EX^2-(\mathsf EX)^2$ and:

$\mathsf EX^2=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y))=\dots$

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I work around between the two distributions?

Comment: Have you been able to find $\mathsf{Var}X$? If so then your question has been answered. If not then tell me where you get stuck. I don't really understand what you are asking in your comment. You could make it more clear, but if it is not about finding expectation and variance then you should ask a new question on this site.